# Need to test if a time is between two other times on same day

Tags: go, time, between

In Go, how do I find if a time is between two other times, ignoring date.

Date is immaterial since the times are got from literals that don't allow a date to be specified.

Begin time is guaranteed to be earlier than end time
For example

Is time 10:00  between 09:00 and 13:00? - yes so true
Is time 14:12  between 02:00 and 03:00? - no so false

Comment: In case of times formatted as HH:mm it is perfectly OK to compare them lexicographically. This is a nice property of dates formatted with ISO 8601. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Grzegorz Żur's comment is really helpful - simplifies the code a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to compare the date, then simply ignore the date when parsing the times.

https://play.golang.org/p/dklyN7NuC5a

```
start, _ := time.Parse("15:04", "14:00")
end, _ := time.Parse("15:04", "15:00")

t, err := time.Parse("15:04", "14:12")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println(start.Before(t) && end.After(t))
```

If you have no need for any of the other time functions, and your clock times are always formatted in `HH:mm`, then you can compare them lexicographically:

```
start := "14:00"
end := "15:00"

t := "14:12"

fmt.Println(start < t && t < end)
```

Comment: I don't *think* the docs make it clear that date can be ignored in this way.